# Basic anonymous user rating system - not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm working on a rating system and the html/jquery codes works well so far:

[Short Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvd4h.png)

The idea is that users can rate specific items with 1 (bad), 2 (neutral) or 3 (good). In my code, all thumbs that belong to one item share the same id, e.g.

```
<i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-1.5x" data-index="0" id="0"></i> 
<i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-1.5x" data-index="1" id="0"></i>
<i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-1.5x" data-index="2" id="0"></i>
```

Then, I store all ratings in 'ratedArray' using the index of the item as the place for the rating at the in the array, so for the short example the corresponding 'ratedArray' the array is

```
ratedArray = [1, 2, 0, 2]
```

(you always have to add 1 for the actual rating, so 1 in the array means 2 thumbs or neutral)

Now I want to save this array and the userID (which I just store a new one in the local storage for each visitor) to my DB with

```
    function saveToTheDB(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "betrayal.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                save: 1,
                uID: uID,
                ratedArray: ratedArray
            }, success: function(r) {
                uID = r.id;
                localStorage.setItem('uID', uID);
            }
        });
    }
```

So far so good but now the trouble starts due to my lack of skill (just started with web design). To my first question: I will have 17*4 = 68 items that can be rated for. Since I plan to store the ratings with a unique ID, I wanted to make the DB look like this

1. id | 0 1 2 3 ... 68 |
2. 1   | 1 0 2 2 ... 0  |
3. 2   | ...            |

because I want to be able to calculate the average rating for each item to color the background depending on the average value. Does this make sense or is there a better way to store my data?

My second question is how I am able to store the array properly in the db. There should be 2 options available: create new entry if user id is not in db or update entries if user id is already in db. My current (not working) code looks like

```
// connect to the data base
$conn = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'db');

if (isset($_POST['save'])){
    // ???
    $uID = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['uID']);
    $rateArray = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['ratedArray']);

    // create star rating for new uID
    if (!$uID) {
        $conn->query( "INSERT INTO db (id, 0, 1, 2, 3, *etc*) VALUES ('$uID', '$rateArray')");
        $sql = $conn->query( "SELECT ID FROM db ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
        $uData = $sql->fetch_assoc();
        $uID = $uData['ID'];

    // update star rating if uID already exists
    } else
        //???;

    exit(json_encode(array('id' => $uID)));
}
```

Also, could I use the IP adress instead of the userID to make the rating system more reliable?

I'd be greatful, if you could give me some basic tips. Cheers,

M.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do. You are mixing different things. Please consider to clarify your question a little bit more.

Comment: First thing: same ID on multiple objects is a violation of W3C standard. ID = UNIQUE per element, CLASS = you can have as many as you want.

Comment: I will give you some good tips, but please answer the next questions. 1. Who is voting? Users? What they are voting? A product? I need this basic info so I can make you a simple database schema that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote you above, I came with a simple database schema so you can better understand how you should build your application. It will seem that is more complex than what you did, but its not. Please check it and ask if anything is unclear in comments.

Only after you understand why you should implement this basic schema from bellow, we should move to PHP and jQUERY code.

Tip: use phpMyAdmin tool as a graphical interface to manage your database.

**Database logical scheme**

[image: simple database logical scheme]

**PHP Basic Logic**

```
<?php
// our answer will be a valid JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');


// function that encodes our response
function respond($status, $arr = array()){


    // add our status, to final answer
    $arr['status'] = $status;


    if ($status != 'success'){
        if ($status != 'internal_server_error'){
            // Specific to server side errors
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
        } else {
            // Specific to client side errors
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    exit();
}


if (isset($_POST['item_id'], $_POST['vote_given'])){

    // validate user data
    $errors = array();

    if (!is_numeric(($_POST['item_id'])){
        $errors['item_id'] = 'value is not numeric';
    }

    if (!is_numeric(($_POST['vote_given'])){
        $errors['vote_given'] = 'value is not numeric';
    } else {

        $vote_given = (int)$_POST['vote_given'];

        if ($vote_given < 0 || $vote_given > 2){
            $errors['vote_given'] = 'value is outside accepted interval [0,2]';
        }
    }

    // if there are errors, then throw them back to user
    if (count($errors) > 0){
        respond(
            'field_validation_errors', 
            $errors
        );
    }


    $item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
    $user_finger_print = sha1($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])

    // At this point we have three numeric values to work with
    // item_id, vote_given, user_fingerpint


    // SQL logic
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* check connection */
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");


    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        respond(
            'internal_server_error', 
            array(
                'code'    => 1,                         // no more details as it is a security leackage
                'message' => 'Ops! There is an Internal Server Error. Please come back later...'
            )
        );
    }


    // SQL query
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    INSERT INTO `products_votes`
        (`item_id`,`user_finger_print`,`vote_given`) 
    VALUES
        (?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `vote_given`= ?")

    // DUPLICATE KEY WILL BE TRIGGERED ONLY IF YOU SET THIS RESTRICTION IN PHPMYADMIN FOR `user_finger_print` and `item_id` columns inside `items_votes` table


    $stmt->bind_param("i", $item_id);             // first  ? (question mark) will be replaced by (i)nteger $item_id
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_finger_print); // second ? (question mark) will be replaced by (s)tring $user_finger_print
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $vote_given);         // third  ? (question mark) will be replaced by (i)nteger vote_given
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $vote_given);         // last   ? (question mark) will be replaced by (i)nteger vote_given

    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->errno){

        $stmt->close();

        respond(
            'internal_server_error', 
            array(
                'code'    => 2,                         // no more details as it is a security leackage
                'message' => 'Ops! There is an Internal Server Error. Please come back later...'
            )
        );
    }
    // close statement
    $stmt->close();

    // close sql connection
    $mysqli->close();

    // respond back to user
    respond('success');

} else {
    respond(
        'error', 
        array(
            'message' => 'POST data is missing'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

It may have a few errors, as I wrote it in Notepad++ but you should get the logic from it.

**HTML  code**
I removed the **id** attribute because it was not necessary, and also added **data-itemid="XXXXX"** attribute to the wrapping parent. I added this information to the wrapping parent to prevent duplicating it for each `<i>` element.

```
<div class="item-vote-wrapper" data-itemid="1">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-1.5x" data-index="0"></i> 
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-1.5x" data-index="1"></i>
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-1.5x" data-index="2"></i>
</div>
```

**jQUERY code**
I added comments inside code, so please read them.

```
$('body').on('click', '.far.fa-thumbs-up', function(){

    let data_for_ajax = {};

    // $(this) is the <i> element that was clicked
    let vote = $(this).data('index');

    // $(this).parent() - is the parent of this <i> element, meaning div with class "item-vote-wrapper"
    let item_id = $(this).parent().data('itemid');



    // Append values to our object
    data_for_ajax['item_id']    = item_id;
    data_for_ajax['vote_given'] = vote;



    $.ajax({
        url: "betrayal.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: data_for_ajax, 

        // Server returns a status code between 200 and 399
        success: function(response) {

            // This code will execute only when the request succeded
            console.log(response);

        },

        // Server returns a status code between 400 and 505
        // Please read this document to understand them better: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_status_codes.htm
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

            console.log("An error occured. Request ended with status: " + textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);

            alert('An error occured. Open DEV tools by pressing F12 and check Console tab');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Good advice, thanks! Users (not customers, basically anyone on the internet) should be able to vote for a specific item or product as you have called it once. 

The body of the final website should look similar to this picture except that there are 3 thumbs underneath each item: i.redd.it/5labrnudkw421.png

Your scheme looks reasonable to me, except that product_name and user_name are not required because the items are static and the user name is not from interest. My problem now is that I have no clue how to translate this scheme into actual code.. Sorry, just fluent in Matlab and Python

Comment: So, we will drop the users table as it is no longer relevant. You will have a unique fingerprint per session_id() + user_ip + user_request_agent(). I do not recommend this technique, since any bad intentioned user could make a tiny script and send more than 100k requests towards your vote script and trash all of your data. To bypass this you may search for CSRF tokens and  OWASP cheatsheet. Now I will update my answer to reflect better your needs.

Comment: @MP install phpMyAdmin tool. Its a great way to manage a mySQL database. Search on Google how to do it. After this, it's very intuitive to create a database and tables.

Comment: Thanks, I've already installed phpmyadmin (using xampp). The db you've proposed is set up but I'm not sure how to connect the item id's in both tables, as doing so in the designer didn't yield any visible connection between them too.

Comment: Also, the website returns 

{
    "message": "POST data is missing",
    "status": "error"
}

using your code (thx btw, very helpful) which indicates that one variable is not set properly. Is it because of

  function saveToTheDB(){
   $.ajax({
    url: "betrayal.php",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
     save: 1,
     item_id: item_id,
     vote_given: vote_given
    }, success: function(r) {
     // 
    }
   });
  }

Also, when would you recommend setting vote_given? Why are there 3 cases of vote_given? I mean, it can be yes or no (1/0), right?

Comment: I did, thanks. It still throws an empty array if I check with isset() but if I check print_r($_POST); at the very beginning of the php script, it returns:

Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundaryxp2KAAMHLwFof8HL
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "item_id"

0
------WebKitFormBoundaryxp2KAAMHLwFof8HL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="vote_given"

2
------WebKitFormBoundaryxp2KAAMHLwFof8HL--

)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I updated the jQuery code and removed the form object, and kept it as a simple object. I also removed dataProcess property. Whenever you see "WebKitFormBoundaryxp2KAAMHLwFof8HL" in var dump that means that the form data was sent as `multipart/form-data` (used for file upload) instead of `x-www-form-urlencoded` used for simpler POST requests.

Comment: Hey Besciualex, thanks. I already voted for you but it seems that my rank is too low for it to be visible..

Answer (score 0):

In the html , id of i isn't unique.
In php u don't update with insert because u generate a new id(AI), u can put a query and after a if , if find a record using a update query , dont find use a insert